# How to resole Dropbox UID to user's email?

Tags: events, dropbox, dropbox-api

When a folder is shared from an outsider user - to somebody inside my Team,
I need to get the email address of the external user.

If I query for the shared folder information (`https://api.dropbox.com/1/shared_folders/826357016`)

we get the following info:

```
{
   shared_folder_name: "ExternalDir"
   shared_folder_id: "826357016"
   access_type: "editor"
   shared_link_policy: "all"
   groups: [0]
   owner: {
           display_name: "External User - Full Name"
           uid: 6920861
           same_team: false
          }
   path: "/ExternalDir"
}
```

Info about the external owner includes a `display_name` and `uid`.

---

1. `display_name` - is not unique or trustworthy
2. `uid` - is useless, as there is no API to query for further information

---

But, on the Dropbox website - they do give the email address!!
   take a look at the popup in this screenshot:
[image: Dropbox Website - Folder Sharing]
How can I resolve the `uid` to an `email_address` like the GUI does?

Comment: I doubt that you will get that information without authorization by the user. The mere fact that you can see something on the website does not mean that it is automatically available unrestricted to you via API as well.

Comment: There isn't a public method for converting Dropbox uid to email address, but we are tracking this as a feature request for adding email address to the authenticated shared folder metadata API call.